# What is the difference between public function and function added using prototype in Object Oriented Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, prototype

I am trying to understand what is the difference when we write:

```
var Foo = function (){
 this.name = 'abc';
 this.alertName1 = function(){
  alert(this.name);
 }
}

Foo.prototype.alertName2 = function(){
  alert(this.name);
 }
```

**Both methods will be available and are correct but when to use what is the question?**

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

When you add a function to the prototype, it only exists in one place no matter how many times you instantiate Foo.

When you add a function inside the constructor, a new copy is created every time you instantiate so it's less efficient.

Comment: Or in the constructor you can have _this.func = funcName;_ to use a function defined elsewhere that exists in only one place. (An option that may make sense together with some conditional logic that selects from several possible functions.)

Comment: Yeah, although you could put that conditional logic inside a function on the prototype ;-)